# print_r($arrayname, boolean); Why is the boolean used?

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

I'm just starting out learning PHP, learning from a few sources. I would like to know why the print_r function requires the boolean value.

```
<?php 

$names = array('Jeff','James','Jeremy');
echo '<pre>', print_r($names), '</pre>';

?>
```

OUTPUT:

Array
(
    [0] => Jeff
    [1] => James
    [2] => Jeremy
)

If i don't include the boolean value, the output comes with an integer "1" at the end of the array. Like this:

Array
(
    [0] => Jeff
    [1] => James
    [2] => Jeremy
)
1

Can anybody help me out with this? Would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: skip `echo`, use `print_r($names)`

Comment: I understand that solves the problem, but i'm more interested in why that occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the documentation at php.net the boolean suppresses the output and returns it (using output buffers).
at this point of code, this makes no sense, until you want to assign the output of `print_r()` into a variable.
So these both lines are in fact the same:

```
echo print_r($names, true);
print_r($names);
```

see docu for details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

since you just edited your question, here is the answer:
you want to put `pre`-tags  arouond your code. and usually you want to escape html-characters.
so you suppress the output to get it parsed by a call of `htmlspecialchars()`

```
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(print_r($names,true)) , '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the second argument as true means that print_r returns the contents for you to do something with, mostly store in a variable. Specifying it as false, or omitting it, means the contents get printed.